# yii2 API rules. Работа с методами

Tags: yii2, api

Я столкнулся с проблемой, что когда я перехожу по пути `http://taxichoice.loc/api/web/v1/uklons` , автоматически срабатывает метод GET и он идет в модель, чтобы взять данные с таблицы. Я не нуждаюсь в методе GET, я хочу работать только с POST. Как сделать так, чтобы при каких то других методах, выходила ошибка что метод не поддерживается.

мой код в main.php

```
'rules' => [
            [
                'class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule',
                'controller' => ['user', 'site', 'v1/uklon'],
                'tokens' => [
                    '{id}' => '<id:\\w+>'
                ],
                'extraPatterns' => [
                    'GET site/error'=>'error',
                    'POST /' => 'get-price',
                ]
            ],
        ],
```

Ошибка которая выводится

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В контроллере есть метод, который возвращает массив какие методы для каких действий использовать.

Comment: Замени в своём конфиге `extraPatterns` на `patterns` и по идее должны работать только запросы которые ты там прописываешь

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В контроллере можно добавить такой метод, который возвращает соответствующий массив. Данный массив будет использован в `VerbFilter::actions`

```
protected function verbs()
{
    return [
        'orderProcessing' => ['POST'],
        'create' => ['POST'],
        'status' => ['GET'],
    ];
}
```